# Creating two objects in one controller and attaching them to each other in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Context**

I'm making an exercise app and I'm having trouble connecting two models, Workouts and Workout_Equipment.  `Workout` includes an `exercise_id`, a `session_id`, and a `workout_equipment_id`.  `Workout_Equipment` is an equipment_id and a weight.  The workout/new looks like this

[image]

**The Code**

`Workout_equipment` isn't something I want people to make manually, I want it to be created when `Workout` is created, so I have something like this

```
def create
   @workout_equipment = WorkoutEquipment.create(workout_equipment_params)
   @workout = Workout.create(workout_params)
end

def workout_equipment_params
   params.require(:workout_equipment).permit(:workout_id, :equipment_id, :weight)
end

def workout_params
   params.require(:workout).permit(:exercise_id, :session_id, :workout_equipment_id) 
end
```

The relevant models have (seemingly) all the necessary foreign-keys.  `Workout_equipment` is being crated first, and I want to subsequently create a `Workout` based on the exercise and session parameters, as well as the freshly created `Workout_equipment`'s id.

**The Problem**

Here's what's happening when I hit submit:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"RjL7oiO0Bk028VXBbwVDmzSAvDIud5aWzGkJ4nMKn3qOj9QOUpowdMYNJaUsPy4nuG2o0xgpkF/uHXzhs2U6bw==", "workout"=>{"exercise_id"=>"4", "session_id"=>"3"}, "workout_equipment"=>{"equipment_id"=>"4", "weight"=>"9001"}, "commit"=>"Create Workout"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "workout_equipments" ("equipment_id", "weight", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["equipment_id", 4], ["weight", 9001.0], ["created_at", "2016-01-24 18:24:16.696192"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-24 18:24:16.696192"]]
   (7.8ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "workouts" ("exercise_id", "session_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["exercise_id", 4], ["session_id", 3], ["created_at", "2016-01-24 18:24:16.705751"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-24 18:24:16.705751"]]
   (5.7ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
```

As you can see, Workout_equipment_id is not being inserted into the `Workout` object, and that makes sense because it's not anywhere in the parameters.  The `create` method only takes one parameter, so if I want to put the id in somewhere, it's going to have to include the params.

So in a situation like this, where I have to add some extra parameters to a create method, how do I get around having my parameters tied to a form?

**Models**

```
class WorkoutEquipment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :workout
  has_many :equipment

end

class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :session
  has_many :workout_equipments

end
```

Comment: Is `WorkoutEquipment` something which is unique to a workout  or should all Workouts that use for example the 10kg dumbbell use the same `WorkoutEquipment` id?

Comment: I think it's probably going to end up polluting a database and I should find a better way to do it but I'm planning on sharing the workout_equipment. In other words, the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delay the creation of your object a little.

```
@workout = Workout.new(workout_params)
@workout.workout_equipment_id = @workout_equipment.id
@workout.save
```

Comment: This is a good start, but I've put `@workout.workout_equipment.equipment_id = @workout_equipment.id` and I'm receiving an error: `undefined method `each' for #<WorkoutEquipment:0x007ff19be5b2a0>`  I've looked around but I still don't understand why it's throwing an each error.

Comment: I can't tell if i don't see the code that's calling `each` method. From the looks of it, you're calling `each` on an object that's not a collection, but a single WorkoutEquipment object.

Comment: Some fiddling in the interpereter shows the assignment `@workout.workout_equipment =...` will call `each` on whatever it's assigned to, even if it's a fixed number.  Do you have any idea why that is?  Keep in mind that up to this point, this has been a pretty by-the-book project, and there's little deviation from the Rails Guides.

Comment: Done.  From what I'm seeing, this is normal behavior for ruby, there are a lot of questions like this but none that seem to actually address the problem.

Comment: I've asked specifically for model code for a reason. Your Workout model clearly states that one Workout corresponds to many WorkoutEquipments (when it should be the other way around, at least judging by your foreign keys). If your 'workouts' table  contains a "workout_equipment_id", it should have `belongs_to :workout_equipment` directive, not `has_many`.

Comment: Now I'm getting an uninitialized constant error... but I think you've taken me far enough through the debugging process, so I hereby release you :P  Thanks for the help!